# Average days between two dates by ID (but only for rows before current row)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to calculate the average number of days between the start date and end date for each id, with one catch...  It has to be avg as of the previous row/date.  I'm completely stumped.

**Before**

```
id  date_start  date_end
1   3/3/2015    3/24/2015
1   3/27/2015   4/14/2015
1   4/15/2015   4/30/2015
1   5/1/2015    5/13/2015
1   5/17/2015   5/28/2015
1   7/9/2015    8/7/2015
2   3/7/2015    3/11/2015
3   2/17/2015   4/8/2015
3   4/13/2015   5/5/2015
4   3/12/2015   3/25/2015
4   3/25/2015   4/3/2015
4   4/3/2015    4/10/2015
4   4/10/2015   4/18/2015
5   5/13/2015   6/12/2015
5   6/12/2015   7/15/2015
5   4/19/2015   5/13/2015
```

**After**

```
id  date_start  date_end    AVG_previous_cycle_days
1   3/3/2015    3/24/2015   NULL
1   3/27/2015   4/14/2015   21
1   4/15/2015   4/30/2015   19.5
1   5/1/2015    5/13/2015   18
1   5/17/2015   5/28/2015   16.5
1   7/9/2015    8/7/2015    15.4
2   3/7/2015    3/11/2015   NULL
3   2/17/2015   4/8/2015    NULL
3   4/13/2015   5/5/2015    50
4   3/12/2015   3/25/2015   NULL
4   3/25/2015   4/3/2015    13
4   4/3/2015    4/10/2015   11
4   4/10/2015   4/18/2015   9.67
5   5/13/2015   6/12/2015   NULL
5   6/12/2015   7/15/2015   30
5   4/19/2015   5/13/2015   29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculation as a cumulative sum divided by the cumulative count -- but you have to subtract out the current value:

```
select t.*,
       ( (sum(diff) over (partition by id order by date_start) - diff) /
         (count(*) over (partition by id order by date_start) - 1)
       ) as avg_through_previous
from t cross apply
     (values (datediff(day, date_start, date_end)) v(diff);
```

Actually, you can also express this using a windowing clause:

```
select t.*,
       avg(diff) over (partition by id
                       order by date_start
                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                      ) as avg_through_previous
from t cross apply
     (values (datediff(day, date_start, date_end)) v(diff);
```